# c++ multi threading priority implementation failed

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-priority

=)

i am a new user here, and I am new to c++, so it is a bit hard for me to work on it...
so i am asking you guys some questions! =)

i am doing a work for school, that asks me to implement threading priority into this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>

int sched_yield(void);

// Parameters to print_function.

struct char_print_parms{
    char character; // char to print
    int count; // times to print
};

void* char_print (void* parameters){
    int i;
    struct char_print_parms* p;

    p = (struct char_print_parms*) parameters;
    for (i = 0; i < p->count; ++i){
        fputc (p->character, stderr);
        sched_yield();
    }
    return NULL;

}

int main (){

    pthread_t thread1_id,thread2_id;
    struct char_print_parms thread1_args,thread2_args;

// Create a new thread to print 200 x's.

    thread1_args.character = 'x';
    thread1_args.count = 200;
    pthread_create (&thread1_id, NULL, &char_print, &thread1_args);

// Create a new thread to print 200 o's.

    thread2_args.character = 'o';
    thread2_args.count = 200;
    pthread_create (&thread2_id, NULL,
    &char_print, &thread2_args);

// main waits for the threads to complete

    pthread_join(thread1_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2_id, NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

This gives is "oxoxoxo..." etc.

The objective is to get more "o", until it finishes.

What I did was:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>

int sched_yield(void);

// Parameters to print_function.

struct char_print_parms{
    char character; // char to print
    int count; // times to print
};

void* char_print (void* parameters){
    int i;
    struct char_print_parms* p;

    p = (struct char_print_parms*) parameters;
    for (i = 0; i < p->count; ++i){
        fputc (p->character, stderr);
        sched_yield();
    }
    return NULL;

}

int main (){

    pthread_t thread1_id,thread2_id;
    struct char_print_parms thread1_args,thread2_args;


    //new code lines
    struct sched_param param;
    pthread_attr_t pta;
    pthread_attr_init(&pta);
    pthread_attr_getschedparam(&pta, &param);
    //end of new code lines

// Create a new thread to print 200 x's.

    thread1_args.character = 'x';
    thread1_args.count = 200;

    //more new code lines
    param.sched_priority = 0;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&pta, &param);
    pthread_setschedparam(thread1_id, SCHED_OTHER, &param);
    //end of more new code lines

    pthread_create (&thread1_id, NULL, &char_print, &thread1_args);



// Create a new thread to print 200 o's.

    thread2_args.character = 'o';
    thread2_args.count = 200;

    //more new code lines 2
    param.sched_priority = 10;
    pthread_attr_setschedparam(&pta, &param);
    pthread_setschedparam(thread2_id, SCHED_OTHER, &param);
    //end of more new code lines 2

    pthread_create (&thread2_id, NULL,
    &char_print, &thread2_args);

// main waits for the threads to complete

    pthread_join(thread1_id, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2_id, NULL);

    return 0;

}
```

At the end, I compile and try to run, but it appears an error:

> Segmentation failed (core dumped)

Once again, I am new to c++ and my english is not very good, but I want to try to understand why this does not work. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Run `gdb [yourprogram]` and press `r`. It should then tell you exactly where and what went wrong. You may have to compile your program with the `-g` option. See [gdb tutorial](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/). (From the error message I concluded that you are on Unix using gcc, if not then please specify what you are using.)

Comment: @nwp  Thanks for your help! I am running this code on CodeBlocks, on Ubuntu! It does all that work =) But if I wasn't using CodeBlocks, I would do something like... Compile: gcc -c nchars.c Executable: gcc -o nchars -lpthread nchars.o Its usually what I see to use (according to the professor.........)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `pthread_setschedparam` the thread id variables haven't been initialized yet. So you're trying to change parameters on an indeterminate thread.

The easiest way to change the priority is to do it in the thread themselves.

---

Regarding uninitialized local variables, their values are indeterminate until explicitly initialized. Using uninitialized local variables leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you see the example in the [`pthread_setschedparam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html) you see it being called with [`pthread_self`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) to set the own threads priority. You can use this to either add a field in the structure you pass to the thread that contains the priority, or have a wrapper thread-function which sets the priority and then calls the actual thread function.

Comment: thank you for your help Joachim! =) I guess understood what you meant. Therefore I changed the code order, putting that part below the creation of the thread. But when you said "The easiest way to change the priority is to do it in the thread themselves.", that made me realize that I understand 0 of this... lol

Comment: @user3559945 Updated answer with some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You should first call `pthread_create (&thread1_id, NULL, &char_print, &thread1_args);` to create thread `thread1_id`, then you can set this thread's priority. I modify the code and it works fine.

```
thread1_args.character = 'x';
thread1_args.count = 200;
pthread_create (&thread1_id, NULL, &char_print, &thread1_args);

//more new code lines
param.sched_priority = 0;
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&pta, &param);
pthread_setschedparam(thread1_id, SCHED_OTHER, &param);

// Create a new thread to print 200 o's.
thread2_args.character = 'o';
thread2_args.count = 200;
pthread_create (&thread2_id, NULL, &char_print, &thread2_args);

//more new code lines 2
param.sched_priority = 10; 
pthread_attr_setschedparam(&pta, &param);
pthread_setschedparam(thread2_id, SCHED_OTHER, &param);
```

You can read this link:https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Realtime_Reference_Guide/chap-Realtime_Reference_Guide-Priorities_and_policies.html.

I test this code, but the output is different each time.

Comment: thank you for your time and your reply! =)
I tried, but the result kicks out the same as before.

Comment: thank you friend. I tested, but once again the results always come out the same..
what do you think I may be doing wrong?